# Does this form of participle work well?

Tags: participles

I wonder if this form of the participle can be used, here are two examples.

**Being sold** well by the car dealer, the cars are going to be sold out soon.

**Being cooked** in the right manner, this dish is likely to be chosen by the jury.

Answer (score 1):

Neither sentence is at all idiomatic. What do you mean by 'sold well'? Advertised widely? Sold for a good price?

I would hope that all the dishes in a cookery contest are 'cooked in the right manner' - the winner needs some extra special quality. Grammatically speaking, *having been cooked* would be better.

*Being* at the start of a sentence is usually used with a noun or adjective rather than a verb participle.

> Being a stranger to the town, she soon became lost.
>
> Being tall, he could easily reach the shelf.